# Opencart - Custom New Order Alert Mail

Tags: php, opencart

I want to alter the php/tpl that generates the email that gets sent to the store owner when a new Order comes in.

I cannot find the files I need to do this, and google + opencart forums aren't much help. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The template file is found in `/catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/mail/` called `order.tpl`